# How to perform rolling for loop in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, apply, rolling-computation

I have a pandas df with 3 columns:

```
        Close   Top_Barrier Bottom_Barrier
0       441.86  441.964112  426.369888
1       448.95  444.162225  425.227108
2       449.99  446.222271  424.285063
3       449.74  447.947051  423.678282
4       451.97  449.879254  423.029413
...
996     436.97  446.468790  426.600543
997     438.16  446.461401  426.599265
998     437.00  446.093899  426.641434
999     437.52  446.024365  426.631635
1000    437.75  446.114093  426.715907
```

**Objective:**
For every row, I need to test if any of the next 30 rows Close price touches the top or bottom barrier (from row 0), eg, start from row index 0, test if Close price (441.86) is greater than Top_Barrier (441.96) or lower than Bottom_Barrier (426.36), if it is greater than Top_Barrier, return 1, if it is lower than Bottom_Barrier, return -1. Else, loop to the next row, eg, at index 1, Close price is 448.95, but it is still being tested against barrier price from index 0, ie, Top_Barrier of 441.96, Bottom_Barrier of 426.36. This loop continue until index 29 if Close price never touches the barriers - return 0 if that's the case. Next rolling loop start from index 1 until 30, etc.

**Attempts:**
I tried using .rolling.apply with the following function but I just could not resolve the errors. Happy to explore any other methods as long as it achieve my objective stated above. Thanks!

```
def tbl_rolling(x):
    start_i = x.index[0]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        # the barrier freeze at index 0
        if x.loc[i, 'Close'] > x.loc[start_i, 'Top_Barrier']:
            return 1
        elif x.loc[i, 'Close'] < x.loc[start_i, 'Bottom_Barrier']:
            return -1
    return 0
```

The following then throws IndexingError: Too many indexers

```
test = df.rolling(30).apply(tbl_rolling, raw=False)
```

Comment: What happens if a close prices is Above the Top_Barrier for one records and below the bottom barrier for another record within the thirty days?  What do you want to return?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this - the for loop shall terminate when it touches any of the top or bottom barrier.

Comment: Ultimately the expected outcome is to have a column of labels (1, -1, or 0) indicating that for each row, whether the Close price within the next 30 rows, first touches the top (1), or the bottom (-1), or it stays within the barriers throughout (0).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this if your dataset isn't very big:

```
df = df.reset_index().assign(key=1)

def f(x):
    cond1 = x['Close_x'] > x['Top_Barrier_y'].max()
    cond2 = x['Close_x'] < x['Bottom_Barrier_y'].min()
    return np.select([cond1,cond2],[1,-1], default=0)[0]

df.merge(df, on='key').query('index_y <= index_x').groupby('index_x').apply(f)
```

Output:

```
index_x
0       0
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       1
996     0
997     0
998     0
999     0
1000    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The full df has about 24k rows. While I am still trying to understand how your method works, may I know if your method has the "rolling" effect? ie, .rolling(30)...